# Is there a special name for a field where each number has a square root?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, terminology

For example, not every number in the field of rational numbers with ordinary addition and multiplication has square root.

Is there a special name for a field where each number has a square root? Can anyone help provide some reference? Thank you!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Yes, those fields are called [quadratically closed fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratically_closed_field).

Comment: there's something very satisfying about this ridiculously short answer

Comment: Note that fields with 2 elements are "quadratically closed fields" over which $\hspace{1.77 in}$ the quadratic polynomial ​ $x^2 + x + 1$ ​ has no roots. ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 7):

If you are interested in *ordered* fields in which every *positive* element has a square root, then you are looking for [Euclidean fields](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_field).